# How can I define a new aspectratio for beamer?

Tags: beamer, geometry

I am trying to create a template for making smartphone-compatible (VERTICAL) beamer slides in Latex. Although this can be achieved (to read in landscape mode) by

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
```

I wish to make a template for making beamer slides which can be read in portrait mode. Although I am not a pro in Latex yet, I tried editing some lines in the `beamer.cls` file

```
\DeclareOptionBeamer{aspectratio}[43]{%
\ifnum#1=1610 %
\setlength\beamer@paperwidth{16.00cm}%
\setlength\beamer@paperheight{10.00cm}%
\else\ifnum#1=169 %
\setlength\beamer@paperwidth{16.00cm}%
\setlength\beamer@paperheight{9.00cm}%
```

To these lines I added

```
\else\ifnum#1=916 %
\setlength\beamer@paperwidth{9cm}%
\setlength\beamer@paperheight{16cm}%
```

However, on using

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=916]{beamer}
```

the layout gives the default 4:3 output.
What am I doing wrong? Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What you did (plus adding one more `\fi` at the end of that block) should work. Make sure that you edited a copy of `beamer.cls` and that you put it somewhere TeX can find.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the extra `\fi` did the trick! I forgot to add that I did not use the main `beamer.cls` file. I made a copy in the working directory, renamed it as `mobview.cls` and then made the changes. Now it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks, but I'm not at home right now. If you want to answer, please do :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik No hurry, please answer when you have time, just to remove the question from the unanswered list :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX Okay, will do :-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested; to add a new geometry setting to `beamer`, first make sure you are changing a local copy of `beamer.cls`. You can see where the file is in your computer by looking at the beginning of log:

```
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2019/09/29 v3.57 A class for typesetting presentations
```

then copy that file to the current directory. Rename it if you prefer. Then open the file and look for something like this:

```latex
\DeclareOptionBeamer{aspectratio}[43]{%
  \ifnum#1=1610 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{16.00cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{10.00cm}%
  \else\ifnum#1=169 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{16.00cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{9.00cm}%
  <...>
  \fi\fi<...>
```

Here the `aspectratio` is the option name and `[43]` is the default value. To add a new option, duplicate one block from one `\else\ifnum` to the next and change it as you want:

```latex
  \else\ifnum#1=916 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{9.00cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{16.00cm}%
```

and then make sure to add an extra `\fi` to the end. The whole thing should look like this:

```latex
\DeclareOptionBeamer{aspectratio}[43]{%
  \ifnum#1=1610 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{16.00cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{10.00cm}%
  \else\ifnum#1=169 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{16.00cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{9.00cm}%
  \else\ifnum#1=149 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{14.00cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{9.00cm}%
  \else\ifnum#1=54 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{12.50cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{10.00cm}%
  \else\ifnum#1=43 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{12.80cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{9.60cm}%
  \else\ifnum#1=32 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{13.50cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{9.00cm}%
  \else\ifnum#1=141 %
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{14.85cm}%
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{10.50cm}%
  \else\ifnum#1=916 %                        <
    \setlength\beamer@paperwidth{9.00cm}%     | One more option
    \setlength\beamer@paperheight{16.00cm}%  <
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \fi % One more \fi
}
```

Then using it:

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=916]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces:

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Internally, `beamer` uses the `geometry` package to set the page dimensions.  So you can tell `geometry` to turn the page using the `landscape` option -- this option doesn't *force* landscape, what it does is swap the height and width of the page.

Because `beamer` loads the `geometry` package, you have to use the `\PassOptionsToPackage` method of getting the `landscape` option to the `geometry` package.

(This only works if your desired page size is simply a rotation of an existing one.  If you want an entirely new page size, you'd need the solution from [the answer of Phelype Oleinik](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510654/86).)

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{landscape}{geometry}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{A Portrait Presentation}
\begin{theorem}
Theorems are easier to prove in portrait orientation.
\end{theorem}
\begin{proof}
This frame is its own proof.
\end{proof}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Beamer presentation in portrait orientation]